# How to change the particle angle in Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, particles

Now I met a new question. How to modify every particle's angle to make it toward the center. Just like the images:

Image 1: normal particles effecing:
[image: Image 1: normal particles effecing]

Image 2: which I need:
[Image 2: which I need http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif](http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif)

Answer (score 0):

How about this code? You need to override CCParticleSystemQuad update: or updateQuadWithParticle:newPosition: method for specify the rotation of the particles. CCParticleSystemPoint can't rotate particles.

```
@interface MyParticleSystem : CCParticleSystemQuad
@end

@implementation MyParticleSystem
- (void)updateQuadWithParticle:(tCCParticle*)particle newPosition:(CGPoint)pos
{
    particle->rotation = ccpToAngle(particle->pos) * 180.0f / M_PI;
    [super updateQuadWithParticle:particle newPosition:pos];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you, Kazuki. I have tested your codes, but cannot make every particle towards the center.

Answer (score 0):

In order to turn particles towards their direction of movement (in your case: towards the center), you can do the following:

1. Add the `oldPos` property to the particle `tCCParticle` struct in CCParticleSystem.h
2. Initialize the `oldPos` property with the initial particle position in `initParticle:` in CCParticleSystem.m
3. Update the `oldPos` property with the current particle position in `update:` in CCParticleSystem.m before the new position is computed. I do this in line 512 immediately after checking whether the particle is still alive.
4. Override `CCParticleSystemQuad` as suggested by Kazuki:

   ```
   - (void)updateQuadWithParticle:(tCCParticle *)particle 
                      newPosition:(CGPoint)pos
   {
       CGPoint direction = ccpSub(particle->pos, particle->oldPos);
       CGPoint n = ccpNormalize(direction);
       CGFloat a = -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(ccpToAngle(n) - M_PI_2);
       particle->rotation = a;

       [super updateQuadWithParticle:particle newPosition:pos];
   }
   ```